# Reports - multivalued List

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have a table that list the roles assigned to courses. Many roles to one course. I need to get the assigned roles into my Course report (The tables are related by CourseID). I have been able to get two results so far, neither is what I need. I can get a list of all the roles or I can get just the first role assigned.

In the example image, there should be two roles assigned to this course.

I am not sure how to get the results I need.
[image]

I tried creating a List box, but that did not limit the list by course. I tried a text box but that only brought back one role.

Comment: I can get the sub-form in the report correctly, but the look and feel does not align. I was hoping that there was a way to limit the listbox results by courseID.

Comment: You can limit listbox by courseID - use filter criteria in RowSource that references CourseID textbox. However, listbox does not have CanGrow and CanShrink properties so will not work nicely in report unless you size it large enough to hold all possible items. Either join tables or use subreport.